# ELB not forwarding client IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, haproxy, amazon-elb

So I have AWS ELB sitting in front of haproxy and our app servers behind those (a little crazy, I know). The requests are being logged in both our haproxy servers and application servers as coming from the ip's of the ELB, without showing the true client IP. When we have this setup with just HAproxy and our app servers, there is no issue with the client IP being passed along, but there don't seem to be many configuration options to allow `x forwarded for` headers in ELB. It may be set by default, but it's hard to find if that's true.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If you are using http/https listeners on the load balancer, then the load balancer should be adding the x-forwarded-for header to the request.

Comment: Perfectly sensible configuration, but as @MarkB points out, classic ELB must be in HTTP(S) mode to add the header. If you are running it in TCP mode (for SNI on HAProxy) then you need the Proxy protocol enabled on both ELB and HAProxy.  Please clarify your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

AWS has brought proxy protocol support for TCP ingress on ELB:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/enable-proxy-protocol.html